# php var to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to populate an array using php and javascript. Onclick, I pass a php variable to a function called addToGroup. This function is a java script function that adds the passed var to a javascript array. When looked at the counsel you can see the array get populated on click but when I inspect it says the size is zero. What am I doing wrong? I will attach a part of the code that I do this in. If you need more information I can provide more code. Please let me know if you spot anything wrong! Thank you very much

```
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<form>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter name" />';
        echo '<button type="button" onclick="addToGroup(\'' . $groupName . '\', this.form.user.value)" />Add</button>';
        echo '<button type="button" onclick="removeFromGroup(\'' . $groupName . '\', this.form.user.value)" />Remove</button>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
    echo '<form>';
    echo '<button type="button" onclick="submitChanges()" />Log</button>';
    echo '</form>';

} else {
    echo 'authentication failed.';
    exit;
}
?>

<script>
var groupChangesAdd = new Array();
var groupChangesRemove = new Array();

function addToGroup(groupName, user) {
        if (groupChangesAdd[groupName] === undefined) {
        groupChangesAdd[groupName] = user;
        console.debug(user);
        $('#groupChangesPlus'+groupName).html('+ ' + user + '<br>');
    } else {
        groupChangesAdd[groupName] = groupChangesAdd[groupName] + ', ' + user;
                           $('#groupChangesPlus'+groupName).html($('#groupChangesPlus'+groupName).htm      l() + '+ ' + user + '<br>');
    }
    console.debug(groupChangesAdd);
}
```

Comment: Javascript does not support associative arrays. To accomplish something similar to associative arrays in Javascript, you'll need to use objects. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 0):

So you are using your arrays as associative arrays (or objects) and so ".length" will not work on them. If you want to see if "groupChangesAdd" has something in it, you can log it to your developer console, and inspect it there, or you could use:

```
var groups = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(groupChangesAdd);
console.log(groups.length - 1);
```

Funny thing is that "length" does exist as a property of Object, it just always returns 0. That's why I remove 1 from groups.length.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing: var groupChangesAdd = new Array(); to var groupChangesAdd = new Object();    Thank you for the help!!!